# Min function accepting varying number of arguments in C++17

Tags: c++, library, template-meta-programming, c++17, variadic

Come across this problem once again in the book [*The Modern C++ Challenge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nl9dDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP4&dq=modern%20c%2B%2B%20challenge%20epub&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q=modern%20c++%20challenge%20epub&f=false).

> **18. Minimum function with any number of arguments**
>
> Write a function template that can take any number of arguments and returns the minimum value of them all, using `operator <` for comparison. Write a variant of this function template that can be parameterized with a binary comparison function to use instead of `operator <`.

I wonder how simple and elegant the implementation could be using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). The following is the parameterized version. Ideas?

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Less, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr const T& min(Less less, const T& a, const T& b, const Ts&... rems) {
  if constexpr (sizeof...(rems)) {
    return min(less, std::min(a, b, less), rems...);
  }
  else {
    return std::min(a, b, less);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question! Is `Less` supposed to be a comparison object? (Like one that implement "less than" for type `T`?)

Comment: @user1118321 Yes. `std::less<void>` would also fit :)

Comment: While it's exactly the same number of operations, wouldn't pipelining make it worthwhile to divide-and-conquer rather than chain linearly? That way one would effectively run two or three cmp/cmov ops in parallel. So, basically instead of `min(min(min(min(...` it should expand to `min(min(min(...), min(...)), min(min(), min()))`

Comment: @Damon I would consider it premature optimization here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
template <typename Less, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr const T& min(Less less, const T& a, const T& b, const Ts&... rems) {
```

This function requires a minimum of 2 elements. A minimum element will exist if the user provides a single argument variadic list. Consider handling that.

```
auto& min1 = min(std::less<>{}, 4, 5);  // okay!
auto& min2 = min(std::less<>{}, 4);     // candidate function not viable, reqs 3 args, 2 provided
```

---

```
        return min(less, std::min(a, b, less), rems...);
```

Your approach here uses recursion and implementations are permitted to put a recursion depth limit on `constexpr` calculations. Consider an iterative solution  that expands the pack while calculating the minimum.

```
template <typename Comparator, typename First, typename... Rest>
constexpr decltype(auto) variadic_min(Comparator cmp, First const& first, Rest const&... rest) {
    const First* result = std::addressof(first);

    // cast each evaluated expr to void in case of overloaded comma operator shenanigans
    ((void)(result = std::addressof(std::min(*result, rest, cmp))), ...);

    return *result;
}
```

An explanation with what is going on with the [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
((void)(result = std::addressof(std::min(*result, rest, cmp))), ...);
 ^     ^         ^                                            ^ 
 |     |         |                        expand using comma op
 |     |         safer than built-in, now constexpr in 17
 |     evaluate the expression for each pack variable
 cast to void the entire expression to avoid overloaded comma op.
```

---

Just thinking beyond the standard library and reinventing the wheel. This `min` works fine for homogenous packs. What about heterogenous packs?

```
auto& min1 = min(std::less<>{}, 4, 5, -1);  // min1 = -1
auto& min2 = min(std::less<>{}, 4, 5, -1.); // candidate template ignored...
```

One of the benefits of the conditional operator (`?:`) is that if both resulting expressions return lvalues of the same type, then the result will have the same type. If that type is `T&`, we could assign to that variable. Could we mimic that behavior with `min` and friends?

```
auto a = 4;
auto b = 5;
((b < a) ? b : a)  = 42;        // a = 42, b = 5
min(std::less<>{}, a, b) = 42;  // cannot assign to return value, returns const-qualified type
std::min(a, b) = 42;            // same with standard library.
min(std::less<>{}, 5, 6) = 42   // cannot assign, makes sense!
```

Comment: Wow O_O Need some time to digest.

Comment: Oh, the fold expression is performed on the comma operator. What a trick, but very nice!

Comment: The only disadvantage I can see in your solution is that it cannot be `constexpr`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Lingxi, [It's fine with constexpr](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cmM8CQ)

Comment: @chris Oh my. I didn't expect compiler to be that smart, given the address-of operator in action here.

Comment: @Lingxi, Yeah, `constexpr` has come a long way since its introduction. C++20 will include the ability to make `std::vector` constexpr and will actually include a constexprified vector, unless something big changes in the next year.

Answer (score 12):

This looks nice! Two issues I see here,

1. When compiling your template with `clang`, it refuses the `if constexpr` dispatch for every recursive instantiation with `sizeof...(rems) > 1`, e.g.

   > error: constexpr if condition evaluates to 2, which cannot be narrowed to type `bool` [-Wc++11-narrowing]

   `gcc` seems to accept this, but the fix is quite simple, just be more explicit about it:

   ```
   if constexpr (sizeof...(rems) > 0)
   ```
2. Never underestimate the standard library. You are doing more work than necessary, have a look at overload #4 in the [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) signature. You can expand the parameter pack into a `std::initializer_list` and pass this to `std::min`, which simplifies your template and avoids its recursive instantiation. Additionally wrapping the arguments into a `std::reference_wrapper` ships around unnecessary copies.

   ```
   #include <functional>

   template <typename Less, typename... Ts>
   constexpr decltype(auto) min(Less less, const Ts&... rems) {
       return std::min({std::cref(rems)...}, less).get();
   }
   ```

   The return type of the `std::min` invocation is a `std::reference_wrapper`, to get around this, its `get()` member function is called.

   Of course, you will pay for the construction of `sizeof...(rems)` `std::reference_wrapper` instances and for the `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: 1) I guess clang is standard-compliant here. 2) Emm... Not sure whether the return type is fine. Maybe have `T` deduced from second argument, and have return type explicitly specified as `const T&`? That is, something like `template <typename Less, typename T, typename... Ts>`.

Comment: I added `.get()` on the `std::min` return value to dereference the `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: I think @Snowhawk 's solution beats both of us XD

Comment: You can [see here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dutPVf) how the compiler can optimize out those things you claim you pay for.

Comment: @chris Nice! Can we assume that the same optimization is applied for large objects?

Comment: @lubgr, I don't see why not considering that the reference wrapper is essentially a pointer and the initializer list thus essentially contains pointers regardless of the pointed-to type. I don't see lingering wrappers [in here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7DdweM) with `std::string`.

Comment: @chris That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @chris yea, that works as long as the user remembers to pass a comparator that invokes `std::cref<T>::operator T&()`. Passing a comparator defined with generalized auto params results in `std::cref<T>` arguments that need to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 9):

It works well, according to my simple test program:

```
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    return min(std::less<int>(), 2, 0, 3);
}
```

I suggest that when you present code for review, you include the tests, too - I imagine that your testing is much more thorough than mine, and I'm too lazy to re-create the full suite.  It also helps reviewers identify scenarios that are missing from the tests (or, conversely, scenarios that are redundant).

---

I recommend using perfect forwarding for the comparator:

```
constexpr const T& min(Less&& less,
//                         ^^
```

```
    return std::min(a, b, std::forward<Less>(less));
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's a couple of other uses that need to be forwarded, too.

---

As  lubgr [mentioned](/a/215486), it's worth using an initializer list.  If we want to avoid copying (if the inputs are large, or can't be copied), then we'll want to use a initializer-list of reference wrappers, and use `std::min_element()` (since the initializer-list `std::min()` returns a copy).  That can be achieved like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<typename Less, typename... T>
constexpr auto& min(Less&& less, const T& ...values)
{
    auto const compare_wrapped =
        [&less](auto const&a, auto const& b) {
            return std::forward<Less>(less)(a.get(), b.get());
        };

    auto const list = { std::ref(values)..., };
    auto const smallest =
        std::min_element(list.begin(), list.end(), compare_wrapped);
    return smallest->get();
}
```

```
int main()
{
    auto const a = 3;
    auto const b = 0;
    auto const c = 2;

    auto const& lowest = min(std::less<int>(), a, b, c);

    return &lowest != &b;
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
template<typename Less, typename... T>
constexpr auto& min(Less&& less, const T& ...values)
{
    return std::min({std::cref(values)...,}, std::forward<Less>(less)).get();
}
```

One defect in this implementation is that it will accept xvalues and happily return a (useless) reference in that case.  I think it ought to be possible to distinguish that case, and forward the chosen xvalue as result, but I haven't had time to implement that.

Comment: I don't think perfect forwarding is necessary here. `std::min` takes `less` by value anyway.

Comment: Fair enough - in which case, you end up with exactly lubgr's suggestion (modulo `auto&` vs `decltye(auto)` - I'm not quite sure which is correct.  Possibly the `decltype` version, if it means we get a copy from xvalue arguments but a reference from lvalue arguments; I'd need to check).