# Replacing MIN and MAX macros with type-safe, recursive templates of variable arity

Tags: c++, recursion, template, variadic

I'm currently reading Mastering Perl for Bioinformatics; I'm using the book for learning bioinformatics while implementing the code in C++. I came across a situation where I needed to use the minimum of three numbers, which the author did using a function call `min3` which, as expected, returns the minimum of three numbers.

Rather than using the canonical C-style macro `#define MIN(a,b) ...`, I wanted to try and write more idiomatic C++, first by staying away from macros, and second by using templates to write type-safe, variadic `Min` and `Max` functions.

```
namespace Math
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    constexpr inline auto Max(T1 a, T2 b) noexcept
    {
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Types>
    constexpr inline auto Max(T1 a, T2 b, Types... args) noexcept 
    {
        return Max(a, Max(b, args...));
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    constexpr inline auto Min(T1 a, T2 b) noexcept
    {
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Types>
    constexpr inline auto Min(T1 a, T2 b, Types... args) noexcept
    {
        return Min(a, Min(b, args...));
    }
} // namespace Math
```

Example usage:

```
std::cout << Math::Max(1,2)       << std::cout.widen('\n');
std::cout << Math::Min(3,8,4,3,2) << std::cout.widen('\n');
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

I'm using `std::cout.widen('\n')` so as to not call `std::fflush()` on each call to `std::endl`.

Comment: This happens to be extremely close to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215471/min-function-accepting-varying-number-of-arguments-in-c17). Which assumes C++17 though, maybe you could clarify whether C++17 is available to you?

Comment: There's a small bug in your code. `min(a, b)` should return `a` if `a == b`; it currently returns `b`.

Comment: @lubgr I completely missed that question when I was verifying this wasn't a repost. I can't use C++17 in production yet though, so I suppose I got lucky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation will work nicely for integers, however, it might be doing a lot of copies which could hurt you for more expensive types.

An edge case that might sometimes be useful in case of calling this via a template: the min/max of 1 number.

Your noexcept is wrong in case of throwing copy constructors. You could change this to `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructable<T>)` or fix the remark above and prevent copies.

Looking at the template arguments, you do allow T1 and T2 to be of a different type. I don't see much added value in that, as you would get an obscure error about the `?:` operator.

And to end with a positive note: I really like the constexpr. This allows you to write a unit test as a static_assert.

Comment: I thought allowing for different types might be handy in case you had to compare a long and a double, or something, but I do agree it doesn't seem great in retrospect. I really appreciate the feedback, this gave me a lot to think about